# Trigger a button when enter a button

Tags: javascript

I am trying to append divs into another divs. That works fine. Here I need some helps, In the below code there is a div with content editable and a save and close button. When i click the save button that was append to the div. But I need make the button clickable when I press the Enter Button.

```js
function createNewList(listName) {
  var cardNameFieldElement = $('<div class = "card-name-field" onkeydown=\'cardSave\' style = "white-space : normal; width: 240px; min-height: 60px; border-radius: 3px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; background-color: #ffffff;  " contenteditable = "true" data-placeholder = "Add a Card..."  ></div>');
  var saveCloseCardWrapper = $('<div class ="save-close-card-wrapper" style = "width: 250px; height: 35px;  margin-top: 5px;">  <input class = "save-card" id = \'SAVE_CARD_BTN\' onclick = \'saveNewCard($(this))\' type="button" value="Save" style = "cursor: pointer; width: 60px; height: 30px; background-color: gray; border-color: gray; margin-left: 10px; border-radius: 3px; vertical-align: top;"><img class = "close-card-create" onclick = \'closeCard($(this))\' src = "media/icons/close.png" width="25" height="25" style = "cursor: pointer; margin-top: 4px; margin-left: 3px;"></div>');
}

function saveNewCard(saveCard) {
  var parent = saveCard.closest('.board-list');
  var cardName = parent.find('.card-name-field').text();
  if (cardName !== "") {
    var cardNameElement = $('<div class = "card-name">' + cardName + '</div>');
    cardNameElement.insertBefore(parent.find('.create-card-section'));
    parent.find('.card-name-field').html("");
  }
}
```

Please look the code and give me some help. I tried this method, but it doesn't work.

```
$(".card-name-field").keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    $(".save-card").click();
  }
});
```

Comment: Read about [__`Event delegation`__](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: you can put your controls into a form and call the desired method into onsubmit of form.

Comment: @Melbin Is the `enter` event working ? Because I think you are generating the html content dynamically sometimes event listener attach to it doesn't work so you have to refer to parent element which are already there before dynamic content was inserted. So you attach eventlisteners to dynamicaly created elements like `$(document).find(".card-name-field").keyup( ...` and `$(document).find(".save-card").click(" ..`. There is one more way to do this .

Answer (score 1):

use `trigger( "click" )` instead of `click()`

```
$(".card-name-field").keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    $(".save-card").trigger( "click" );
  }
});
```